# How to set one TableColumn to grow with TableView?

Tags: javafx

I have a `TableView` that will shrink/grow properly as the window is resized.

However, I want one of the columns to automatically grow as well. Similar to how the `HGrow` property works on other nodes.

A `TableColumn` does not seem to have any type of `HGrow` or similar properties to tell that column to use all available space.

I did try to set the `PrefWidth` property to `Double.MAX_VALUE`, but is causing the column to expand indefinitely.

My goal is to have the `TableView` fit within the window and if the window is resized, instead of expanding the last *pseudo* column (which isn't actually a column at all), it will expand the preferred column.

Here is my MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableColumnGrow extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> colFirstName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> colLastName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");

        colFirstName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        colLastName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colFirstName, colLastName);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Martin", "Brody"),
                new Person("Matt", "Hooper"),
                new Person("Sam", "Quint")
        );

        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TableColumnGrow Sample");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}

class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

---

[image: screenshot]

So the goal is to remove the column in red and instead have the "First Name" column take up the extra space (without pushing "Last Name" out of bounds).

Is this possible without resorting to expensive calculations of widths?

**Edit:** While my example does use the first column in the `TableView`, I would want this to be applicable to any column I choose, and regardless of how many columns the `TableView` has.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY

Comment: @brian - As far as I can tell, that affects all columns equally. I need to apply that behavior to only one column...

Comment: It's all there is without adding some code.  It won't be expensive in cpu time to do some calculations, maybe you mean coding time?  You could have done it already:)

Comment: @brian One could interpret the question to be fundamentally asking: _How does one create a custom resize policy_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would take a crack at it. I am basically listening to when a column width changes and when the table width changes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> colFirstName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> colMiddleName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> colLastName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");

        colFirstName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        colLastName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        colLastName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colFirstName, colMiddleName, colLastName);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Martin", "One", "Brody"),
                new Person("Matt", "Two", "Hooper"),
                new Person("Sam", "Three", "Quint")
        );


        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TableColumnGrow Sample");
        primaryStage.show();

        DoubleProperty width = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        width.bind(colMiddleName.widthProperty().add(colLastName.widthProperty()));
        width.addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
            colFirstName.setPrefWidth(tableView.getWidth() - 5 - t1.doubleValue());
        });

        colFirstName.setPrefWidth(tableView.getWidth() - 5 - width.doubleValue());
        colFirstName.setResizable(false);

        tableView.widthProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
            colFirstName.setPrefWidth(tableView.getWidth() - 5 - width.doubleValue());
        });
    }
}

class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty middleName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
        this.middleName.set(middleName);
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty middleNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close.But it doesn't allow manually resizing the the 2nd "Last Name" column. It doesn't look like there's going to be an elegant solution to make the columns behave like a `VBox` with an appropriately set `HGrow` property, I suppose.

Comment: It does. You just have to move the bar a little to the right. The easy fix  is to do something like `colFirstName.setPrefWidth(tableView.getWidth() - 5 - t1.doubleValue());`.You might have to play with the 5 to stop the sliding bar from showing the the bottom. @Zephyr.

Comment: Ah. Good call! I didn't even notice the scroll bar at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: This does, indeed, work very well. A little strange behavior wise because you can't manually resize "First Name," but I don't know how else I would expect that part to behave anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Yea. That's the drawback.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a combination of setting the `TableView#setColumnResizePolicy` to `TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` and binding a width property of the column (or columns) you want to control to the width property of the table itself. I believe this is similar to what [brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2855515/brian) is alluding to.

Below is an example.

```
package tmp_table;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      var people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
          new Person("John Doe", "Male"),
          new Person("Jane Doe", "Female")
      );
      var table = new TableView<Person>(people);
      var nameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Name");
      var genderCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Gender");

      nameCol.setCellValueFactory(
          cell -> cell.getValue().nameProperty());
      genderCol.setCellValueFactory(
          cell -> cell.getValue().genderProperty());

      table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
      // this gives name column 70% of table width, the 
      // CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY will make the other
      // remaining columns fill the table width equally
      nameCol.minWidthProperty().bind(
          table.widthProperty().multiply(0.7));

      table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
      table.getColumns().add(genderCol);

      var stackPane = new StackPane(table);
      StackPane.setAlignment(table, Pos.CENTER);
      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 400, 200));
      primaryStage.show();
  }
}

class Person {
    StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    StringProperty gender = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Person(String name, String gender) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.gender.set(gender);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public StringProperty genderProperty() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Won't this force the table column to _always_ be at least 70% of the table's width?

Comment: @Slaw yes, that is the intent I was after. The OP does not specify a fixed amount that the column (first name in their example I believe) should be so I just randomly through one out there. Can you clarify if this does not get the point across for your issue at hand?

Comment: My problem is, it seems like the OP wants to be able to arbitrarily resize all other columns while having the first column fill the remaining space—which may be _less_ than 70% of the table's width.

Comment: I see your point. If that is the case OP can bind max width on the other columns, remove the min width binding and you’re off to the races. The general principle is the same so, without clarification I’ll leave it as is.

Comment: @slaw is correct. I want maintain the ability for the user to resize the columns as they wish, but expand the first column automatically if extra space becomes available (such as when maximizing the window, for example).

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solution if you say you dont want to alter the other columns width.

Include this after your tableView and column declarations.

**UPDATE : Sorry didnt noticed the last line of the question.(regarding calculations). So if it not suits you, discard this solution.**

```
TableColumn<?, ?> columnToResize = colFirstName;
tableView.widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, width) -> {
    double otherColsWidth = tableView.getColumns().stream().filter(tc -> tc != columnToResize).mapToDouble(tc -> tc.getWidth()).sum();
    double padding = tableView.getPadding().getLeft() + tableView.getPadding().getRight();
    columnToResize.setPrefWidth(width.doubleValue() - otherColsWidth - padding);
});
```

**Update 2:**

If you want a little more flexibility of resizing hgrow column when other columns are resized below is a quick demo. Just note that resizing the hgrow column itself has no specific code as it depends up to you how to handle that case.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableColumnGrow extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        HGrowTableView<Person> tableView = new HGrowTableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> colFirstName = new HGrowTableColumn<>("First Name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> colLastName = new HGrowTableColumn<>("Last Name");

        colFirstName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        colLastName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        tableView.setColumnToResize(colLastName);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colFirstName, colLastName);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Martin", "Brody"),
                new Person("Matt", "Hooper"),
                new Person("Sam", "Quint")
        );
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TableColumnGrow Sample");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * Custom Table View
     *
     * @param <S>
     */
    class HGrowTableView<S> extends TableView<S> {
        TableColumn<?, ?> columnToResize;
        ChangeListener<Number> tableWidthListener = (obs, old, width) -> {
            double otherColsWidth = getColumns().stream().filter(tc -> tc != columnToResize).mapToDouble(tc -> tc.getWidth()).sum();
            double padding = getPadding().getLeft() + getPadding().getRight();
            columnToResize.setPrefWidth(width.doubleValue() - otherColsWidth - padding);
        };

        public void setColumnToResize(TableColumn<?, ?> columnToResize) {
            widthProperty().removeListener(tableWidthListener); // Ensuring to remove any previous listener
            this.columnToResize = columnToResize;
            if (this.columnToResize != null) {
                widthProperty().addListener(tableWidthListener);
            }
        }

        public TableColumn<?, ?> getColumnToResize() {
            return columnToResize;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom TableColumn
     *
     * @param <S>
     * @param <T>
     */
    class HGrowTableColumn<S, T> extends TableColumn<S, T> {
        public HGrowTableColumn(String title) {
            super(title);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, width) -> {
                if (getTableView() instanceof HGrowTableView) {
                    TableColumn<?, ?> columnToResize = ((HGrowTableView) getTableView()).getColumnToResize();
                    if (columnToResize != null && HGrowTableColumn.this != columnToResize) {
                        double diff = width.doubleValue() - old.doubleValue();
                        columnToResize.setPrefWidth(columnToResize.getWidth() - diff);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close, but suppose I want a column other than the first one? If I set this on `colLastName` and then resize `colFirstName`, it will push `colLastName` outside of the visible area...

Comment: Updated the code as per your comment. If you want to add more features,. i think it would be good to extend the classes .. rather than tweaking them externally.

Comment: hmm ... seems to not work for more than 2 columns? Just added another lastName column, then resizing the second column pushes the last off (or makes empty space visible). What am I missing? BTW,  I don't think that there is a reliable solution without a custom resizePolicy (never tried, though ;)